# NoClassDefFoundError when running app in emulator/phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to manage my Android project, which uses Amazon's Android libraries for AWS. I have added the library jar files to a ./libs folder, from which I added the libraries to my Java Build Path (Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARS...). My app compiles correctly, but when I run it on an emulator or on a phone, I get a NoClassDefFoundError. I understand that this error is usually thrown when the application is compiled correctly but the libraries end up missing from the exported apk file.

Did I miss a step?

Edit:

Here's the stack trace up to the point where my application references it.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams
   at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient.configureHttpClient(Unknown Source)
   at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at lee.medical.icu.dataentry.MainMenuActivity.connectToDb(MainMenuActivity.java:121)
```

Comment: Have you used their starter guide? http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4225549089557252

Comment: I reread the guide and tried using External JARs instead. It still doesn't work, oddly enough.

Comment: Using the right SDK version? Clean and Build? AWS access credentials?

Comment: Yup, yup, and yup. Although, now that you mentioned AWS access credentials, I forgot to mention that the app doesn't seem to fail when it creates the AWSCredentials object, but fails when it tries to create an AmazonSimpleDB object. I have edited my original post to include the stack trace.

Comment: Also, strangely enough, I can run the Android sample that they provided.

Comment: @Spidy: Just to update you on this question, it turns out that the library files weren't properly built.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I was curious as to why a simple problem like this was taking so long to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the jar files in the AWS SDK weren't properly built. It appears that they missed an old Apache library that is no longer publicly distributed. Amazon has updated the download, and the libraries no longer throw a NoClassDefFoundError.

Source: [Forum post on AWS mobile dev forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=70710&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the libraries in the "Referenced libraries" point in the package view? If not, select the files in the project navigator, right click them "Build path" -> "add to buildpath"

Comment: The library is already under Referenced libraries in package view.

Comment: Huh ... that's strange. +1 because I don't know why your solution doesn't work and because my project works without Spidys solution.

Comment: Just to let you know, I have edited the original question to add the stack trace, in case it is of any help.

Comment: I just want to update you on this question. It turns out the jar files in the SDK were not properly built. Amazon has updated its SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found the resolution in the post below.
in short, you may want to place your external jar file in the libs directory (NOT in lib)
then include it as an external jar file via right click on the project, then

```
properties >> java build path >> add external jars >> libs/yourLibrary.jar
```

the full explanation is [here](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17).