# problem with screen/activities on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setOnClickListener not working and throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684499/setonclicklistener-not-working-and-throwing-error)

I am trying to develop a discount calculator in which there will be a welcome screen and on button click, different calculator will work.

Current I am not getting error but on click of:

**button 1 - Calculator**, I get error on phone **"the application testcalculator stopped - force close"**

when I  click **button 2 - Calculator 2**, I get nothing I don't know why.

Only **button 3** - exit is working

**Below is my complete code / programs:**

**welcome.java**

```
    package com.testcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;





public class welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome1);


        //////// MENU  //////////
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        Button playBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn2);
        playBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);


        Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


   /**
     * Listener for game menu
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.playBtn :

            i = new Intent(this, testcalculator.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.playBtn2 :

            i = new Intent(this, testcalculator2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;


        case R.id.exitBtn :
            finish();
            break;
        }

    }

   }
```

**welcome1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<Button
   android:id ="@+id/playBtn"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Calculator"
/>

<Button
   android:id ="@+id/playBtn2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Calculator2"
/>

<Button
   android:id ="@+id/exitBtn"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Exit"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**testcalculator.java**

```
    package com.testcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class testcalculator extends Activity {


    double initial_price;
    double discount;
    double final_price; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testcalculator);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
              this, R.array.discount, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                if (pos==0){
                    discount=10;
                }
                else if (pos==1){
                    discount=15;
                }
                else if (pos==2){
                    discount=18;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }   
        });

        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText amount1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount1);
                if (amount1.length()>0 ) {
                    initial_price=Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
                    TextView final_price_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_price);
                    final_price=initial_price-(initial_price*discount/100);
                    final_price_text.setText("Final Price : "+final_price);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });       
    }
}
```

**testcalculator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"></Spinner>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter the price" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amount1"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numeric="decimal"></EditText>
    <Button
        android:text="Calculate Result"
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/final_price"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**testcalculator2.java**

```
    package com.testcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class testcalculator2 extends Activity {


    double initial_price;
    double discount2;
    double final_price2;    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testcalculator2);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
              this, R.array.discount2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                if (pos==0){
                    discount2=20;
                }
                else if (pos==1){
                    discount2=25;
                }
                else if (pos==2){
                    discount2=28;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }   
        });

        Button calculate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate2);
        calculate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText amount2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount2);
                if (amount2.length()>0 ) {
                    initial_price=Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
                    TextView final_price_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_price2);
                    final_price2=initial_price-(initial_price*discount2/100);
                    final_price_text.setText("Final Price : "+final_price2);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });       
    }
}
```

**testcalculator2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"></Spinner>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter the price" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amount2"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numeric="decimal"></EditText>
    <Button
        android:text="Calculate Result"
        android:id="@+id/calculate2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/final_price2"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.testcalculator"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".welcome"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".testcalculator" />
        <activity android:name=".testcalculator2" />




    </application>
</manifest>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, testcalculator!</string>
    <string name="app_name">testcalculator</string>
    <string-array name="discount">
        <item>10% discount A</item>
        <item>15% discount B</item>
        <item>18% discount C</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="discount2">
        <item>20% discount A</item>
        <item>25% discount B</item>
        <item>28% discount C</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Please help me!!!**

Comment: What do you get in the logcat output?

Comment: Are both calculator and calculator2 activities listed in your AndroidManifest.xml -> Application (tab) -> Application Nodes section?

Comment: on my screen I see 2 buttons that says: 1) Calculator, 2) Calculator2, 3) Exit. On exit works, calculator2 click doesn't do anything. and pressing 1st button "calculator" gives error message saying _"The application testcalculator (process com.testcalculator) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."_

Comment: this is extension of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684499/setonclicklistener-not-working-and-throwing-error) **NOT duplicate**. That question was for 1 error message (which was solved) and this is complete problem for which **I am not getting desired output**

Comment: It's not helpful to tell us what the error message on the screen is, because it could be cause by almost anything. Open command prompt and run `adb logcat` and tell us what appears in the log when the error occurs.

Comment: I just added logcat lines above, is that what you need because in logcat I see 1000s of lines? Sorry don't have much experience with logcat.

Comment: @super: Have logcat running while you run your app on your phone/emulator. When you hit an error, you'll see a stack trace appear your command window (it looks similar to the stack traces you get when normal Java programs throw uncaught exceptions). Copy that and edit it into your question. If you're not sure how to copy stuff from command prompt, right click the window, select Mark, select the area you want to copy, and hit Enter. You can then paste it here (if you do, format it as code), or paste it on a text pasting site like pastie.org.

Comment: I am running logcat on eclipse: windows > show view > other > logcat. Is this correct ?

Comment: You could do that. It lags a bit behind logcat on command line, but it shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, the output you put in your question isn't exactly helpful because it doesn't have the stack trace. If you're not sure what a stack trace looks like, you can check out [one of my questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526829/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-app-in-emulator-phone). In the meantime, you might want to check out FeelGood's solution; I feel it might be the solution to your current problem.

Comment: yes "FeelGood" solution seems to be working. Talking about about calculation, Right now, if we enter price in decimal or anything, if the final result is in decimal, it is being displayed as EXACT something like 99.9999999

How to limit the RESULT upto 2 decimal points only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your testcalculator.onCreate() and testcalculator2.onCreate() - you use the same main.xml (setContentView(R.layout.main);) which does not contain R.id.spinner1 or R.id.spinner2.

Comment: spinner1 is in testcalculator.xml & spinner2 is in testcalculator2.xml. So this is what I did - changed from  _setContentView(R.layout.main);_ to _setContentView(R.layout.testcalculator);_ (Same with testcalculator2 changed to _setContentView(R.layout.testcalculator2);_). Now I see buttons and button 1 takes me to calculator 1, but button 2 "calculator2" and 3rd button "exit" are not working why ?

Comment: plus I left the main.xml as it is. it is ok ? so I still have 1 main.xml which I don't think is used by any program. is it ok ?

Comment: In first, in welcome.onCreate() you use the same id trying to find diferent buttons - findViewById(R.id.playBtn). As result listener is added only for first button. Adding Log(TAG, "id: " + view.getId()); to onClick() can help you in future.

Comment: Remove main.xml if you do not use it to avoid similar problems in future. If it is used you will see compilation errors.

Comment: hello FeelGood - I just updated my **WORKING CODE**, could you please check my program if logically it is correct and I am following all the programming norms correctly so that I don't face any problem in future?

Comment: Could you please answer the question that I asked above from "GiantMarshmallow" ? thanks

Comment: about TextView - I do not know. about review - remove code duplication. Use one CalculatorActivity with the same layout and switch discounts according to incoming Intent which you construct in WelcomeActivity.onClick() (Intent can hold extras - in your case calculation mode).

Comment: Could you please show me what you mean by _Use one CalculatorActivity with the same layout and switch discounts according to incoming Intent which you construct in WelcomeActivity.onClick() (Intent can hold extras - in your case calculation mode)_ **PLEASE**